# differential equation problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Sorry if you find question too easy but I am really not getting it.I am studying orthogonal trajectory and at start they give example of two family of curves one is $y=mx$ saying this is orthogonal trajectory to family of circles with centre as origin. So I am confused how this lines cuts the circle at right angles means. What's the actual geometrical interpretation.?

Comment: If you plot both sets of curves, the lines will intersect the circles at right angles, ie the lines will look like diameters to the circles. For example http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7By%3D2x,y%3D-x,x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D2,+x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D4%7D you may have to press the equal sign for wolframalpha again to get it to plot it

Comment: that is my question actually... how we can measure the angle between that straight line and circle(which is a rounded  curve)?

Comment: You can find the slope at the point of intersection of any line and any circle and they will be negative reciprocals...Indicating orthogonality

Answer (score 0):

A circle with its center in the origin with radius of $r$ is defined as:
$$x^2+y^2=r^2$$
taking derivative with respect to $x$ from the equation gives:
$$2x+2y'y=0$$
This is the differential equation of the circle. To find the orthogonal trajectories of this equation you need to replace $y'$ with $-\frac{1}{y'}$ to obtain the differential equation of the orthogonal trajectories of the circles:
$$\frac{1}{y'}=\frac{x}{y}$$
$$\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{1}{x}$$
integrating both side with respect to $x$
$$lny =lnx+lnc=lncx$$
and at the end we obtain
$$y=cx$$
for a geometric interpretation you can look at the image below:

[image link](http://d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2Fc2a%2Fc2a88cab-4cf2-4675-a06f-321756f9584a%2Fphp2t1Y4S.png)

Image from "chegg.com".